# Using std::tm as Key in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, function-object

I'd like to use std::tm () as the key for an std::map-container.
But when I try to compile it, I get a lot(10) of errors.

For example:

1.

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator
>   <(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>
>   &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce
>   template argument for 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>
>   &' from 'const tm'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xfunctional   125

2.

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator
>   <(const _Elem *,const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>
>   &)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const _Elem *' from
>   'const tm'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xfunctional   125

3.

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator
>   <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const
>   std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for 'const
>   std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const
>   tm'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xfunctional   125

Does all this mean, that I "simply" have to created an function object which compares two std::tm, because there is no standard-comparison defined for this?
Or is there another trick? (or may it even be impossible to me? ^^)

Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::tm, std::string> mapItem;
    std::tm TM;

    mapItem[TM] = std::string("test");
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::map` uses a comparer to check if the key already exists or not. So when you use `std::tm` , you've to provide a comparer as third argument as well.

```
template < class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key,T> > > class map
```

So a solution would be functor (as you already guessed):

```
struct tm_comparer
{
   bool operator () (const std::tm & t1, const std::tm & t2) const
   {           //^^ note this

        //compare t1 and t2, and return true/false
   }
};

std::map<std::tm, std::string, tm_comparer> mapItem;
                             //^^^^^^^^^^ pass the comparer!
```

Or define a free function (`operator <`) as:

```
bool operator < (const std::tm & t1, const std::tm & t2)
{          // ^ note this. Now its less than operator

    //compare t1 and t2, and return true/false
};

std::map<std::tm, std::string> mapItem; //no need to pass any argument now!
```

Comment: If I would switch to and unordered_map ,would it make this obsolete?

Comment: @Incubbus: No. `unordered_map` would still need it. Because both type of map needs to check the keys. They must check for  *unique* keys.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v1X6tai9 <- does this functor look sufficient enough, if we presume, that someone needs a few seconds to enter stuff (so tm_sec should never be the same)?

Comment: @Incubbus: why can't `tm_sec` be same? `01:30:05` and `03:49:05` both has same `tm_sec`.  What you probably can do is, convert `tm` into number of seconds, and compare only the second. Or if you fear that value would exceed the maximum value of the datatype (`int`, `long long` or whatever you take), then you can convert `tm` into number of `hours`, and `seconds`. For example,  `5 days, 4 hours, 30 minutes, 7 seconds` would become :  `(5 x 24 + 4)` hours and `30 x 60 + 7` seconds. If you do so, then it would be easy to compare.

Comment: @Incubbus: Also, you need to write constructor and destructor in the comparer functor, as the default ones generated by the compiler is enough for you.

Comment: What I intended was: my tm_sec is compared last, so I can ensure that year, day, minute, hour are the same...

the other thing you suggested: this method would be equal to saving the value returned by time(NULL);... i thought it would be easier to handle a ready-converted tm-structure... but as it turned out a few minutes ago: I still have a problem while using this functor and calling find() on the map... there is an runtime error saying: invalid operator<

Comment: @Incubbus: I didn't get what problem you're facing now, and what current implementation you're using now. Can you give me these details?

Comment: when my code reaches `std::map<std::tm, CReminderItem, CCompareTM>::iterator it = m_mapItem.find(Item.GetDate());` it throws an runtime error saying `Expression: invalid operator <` in an include file called xtree (I think it has to do with searching mechanism of the map)

Comment: The free function is illegal, I think, as you're supposed to add only overloads for functions and operators where at least one of the arguments is a UDT outside `namespace std`. Besides, you'd have issues finding it. Name lookup wouldn't look in the global namespace, since neither the caller (std::map) nor the arguments (std::tm) are in the global namespace.

Comment: if found the problem after examining the STL-code... It seems that my function needs to return false in the last spot; at least it makes it work and works correctly after i done some tests

Answer (score 2):

Yes `std::tm` doesn't define a `<` operator.

Answer (score 2):

A free function suffices, you do not need a function object.

Comment: You may use a free `<` operator but you may not supply any free function as the `Compare` parameter of `std::map`, the template definition is `template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>...`

Comment: @Andreas: You are correct. I mixed that up with cases like `for_each`, where the functor can be any callable.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken ;) See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989010/contradiction-in-c-standard

Comment: @Andreas: Good find! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to define operator< for tm structure. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/ for example (bottom of page).