# Contradiction in C++ standard?

Tags: c++

A `std::map` must satisfy the requirements of an associative container specified in paragraph 23.1.2/2:

> Each associative container is
>   parameterized on Key and an ordering
>   relation Compare that induces a strict
>   weak ordering (25.3) on elements of
>   Key. In addition, map and multimap
>   associate an arbitrary type T with the
>   Key. The object of type Compare is
>   called the comparison object of a
>   container. This comparison object may
>   be a **pointer to function** or an object
>   of a type with an appropriate function
>   call operator.

But then in paragraph 23.3.1/2 the `std::map` template is specified as:

```
template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
          class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T> > >
class map;
```

which seems to explicitly prohibit the use of a function pointer as `Compare`. Is this a contradiction or am I not understanding the standard correctly?

**EDIT:** Yes, the problem I was really having was why code like GMan's example:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

bool compare_foo(const foo& x, const foo& y)
{
    return x.x < y.x;
}

std::map<foo, bool, compare_foo> fooMap;
```

wouldn't compile (yeah, I stupidly mixed up the type and value of the `Compare` parameter).

Comment: We'd be able to better answer if you explained *why* you think this somehow "explicitly prohibits the use of a function pointer".

Comment: Next time, perhaps don't go read a specification if you're just learning to use the language. [Use a tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare is the type of the comparator.  The fact that it is declared with `class` instead of `typename` doesn't make a difference, you can have a pointer to function as type and give your function in the map constructor.

```
#include <map>

bool myCmp(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

void foo()
{
    std::map<int, char*, bool (*)(int, int)> m(myCmp);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
class Compare
```

does not mean that Compare has to be a class. It might be clearer if it said:

```
typename Compare
```

You can use any type that provides the comparable function call semantics, such as a function pointer.

Comment: except that Andreas is trying to say he's still confused. As it turns out the real question was why his code won't compile, not what the word class meant. As always, we need to find the real question first :)

Answer (score 3):

Specify it like this:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

bool compare_foo(foo x, foo y)
{
    return x.x < y.x;
}

//                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv function pointer type
std::map<foo, bool, bool(*)(foo, foo)> fooMap(compare_foo);
//                     function pointer value ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes, but the `class` prefixed to Compare seems to make it impossible to specify a function pointer

Comment: When I try to compile this with MSVC10 I get `error C2923: 'std::map' : 'compare_foo' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Pr'`

Comment: Comeau gives `error: function "compare_foo" is not a type name
  std::map<foo, bool, compare_foo> fooMap;`

Comment: Try: `std::map<foo, bool, bool(*)(const foo& x, const foo& y)> fooMap(&compare_foo);`

Comment: @Andreas: Oh, sorry. You didn't really specify *why* you thought it was contradictory, I assumed you thought `=`meant requirement or something. You should add that to your question. `class` is just a keyword with some semantic in template specifications, it doesn't mean anything different from `typename`. And yes, silly mistake on my part, allow me to fix it.

Comment: @GMan:  Why not `bool compare_foo(const foo & x, const foo & y)`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Didn't feel like typing it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the type and the value of the comparator; use this e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<foo, bool, bool(*)(const foo&, const foo&)> fooMap(compare_foo);
}
```